# Horizontal Scrolling buttons in WPF

Tags: wpf, button, wpf-controls, scroll, styling

I have a horizontal stack panel that contains buttons.

I need to be able to scroll this either right or left to make the buttons rotate through the stack panel because there are more buttons than there is room on the screen.

Using a horizontal scroll bar is not an option because it ruins the look of the application and does not rotate all the way around in a circular fashion.

- How can I either change the scroll bar to just have a right arrow on the right hand side and a left arrow on the left hand side to handle the scrolling and not completely rotate all the buttons. ie, works like a normal scroll bar but looks way better. 
  eg.  << [Btn][Btn][Btn] >>
- Or have a way or rotating the buttons in a circular fashion so the is no real start or end the the horizontal collection of buttons and some way for a user to move the position of the buttons they can see.

The container control does  not to have to be a stack panel, that was just the best container for the buttons initially.

Xmal and styling would be my first choice, but there is no issue using code behind either.

Answer (score 0):

Making your own custom scroll buttons is a issue? 
 If not, you can create a ItemsControl, in the style set the ItemsPanel to

```
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelStyle">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

and in the ControlTemplate of the ItemsControl

```
<ScrollViewer
    x:Name="PART_ScrollViewer"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    CanContentScroll="True"
    >
        <ItemsPresenter/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

your toolbar buttons will be the actual ItemsSource of this ItemsControl. If you create now a button in the template (scroll right, the scroll button you need), and on it's command you execute

```
ScrollViewer myViewer = GetTemplatedPart("PART_ScrollViewer");
if(myViewer != null)
{
    myViewer.LineRight();
}
```

this should scroll each element to the right untill the end of your list of buttons (notice advantage: no matter what the width of the element is). 
 The same thing you can do to the left.

HTH, daniell